# Revolution R: filter an xdf using another xdf

Tags: r, hadoop, filtering, subset, revolution-r

I'm trying to filter a very large xdf file (sitting on cloudera) using `in` to compare it to another xdf file (sitting on cloudera).

If I try:

```
rxDataStep(inData = largeXdf,
       outFile = largeXdf,
       overwrite = TRUE,
       transformObjects = 
         list(param1 = parameter),
       rowSelection = (columnNameFromLargeXdf %in% param1$1),
       numRows = -1))
```

I get an error regarding `param$1` saying that objects of class s4 cannot be subsetted.  As in xdf data objects cannot be subsetted.  Is there any way around this? I rather not convert the xdf to a local csv file because it is very large.

Comment: Of what class is `param1`?

Comment: Are there any S4 classes that have redefined `$` so that it can parse an unquoted token that begins with a digit? I would expect that to fail at the parser level, before it even got to evaluation. And please present the entire un-edited error message since "s4" is not a class but rather a name of a broad set of functions. Objects have S4-methods.

Answer (score 1):

`XDFs` can certainly be subsetted, but you can't overwrite an `XDF` on `hdfs`.  You will need to write to a different file. Also, if you are saying that `parameter` is also an `XDF` then the way you are using it in the `rowSelection` is not correct.